# Copying files in a pipeline using cygwin bash shellscript

Tags: cygwin-x

I need to select certain files  in a directory and copy them to another directory using a cygwin script but I cannot get the syntax for the copy.
i.e.

for i in `cat boards`
do
ls -t $work |grep ^$i |cp .............

If I run with just the grep it lists all the files I want but I don't know how to get that on the cp cmnd.

Long time since I did any of this but seem to remember there is an automatic variable containing the input from stdin.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're hunting for [xargs](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs).

```
destination="/path/to/folder"
for i in $(cat boards)
do 
     ls -t $work | grep ^$i | xargs -Isource cp source /path/to/destination
done
```

Run a `for` loop using variable `i` filled with the results of `cat boards` (`$()` spawns a process).

`xargs -Isource` takes the output of `grep ^$i` and feeds it to `cp` in the `source` position of `cp source /path/to/destination`. From the man page:

`-I replace-str
Replace occurrences of replace-str in the initial-arguments with names read from standard input.`

Hope this was what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want all of the copied files to wind up in the same place.

It sounds you want all of the files in /path/to/$work where the filename starts with a line from the boards file to be copied to some destination.

eg., given

```
$ cat boards
start1
start2
$ ls $work
start1.txt
start1.jpg
start2.txt
start2.jpg
start3.txt
$
```

you want start1.txt, start1.jpg, start2.txt, and start2.jpg to be copied to somewhere, but not start3.txt.

Don't use xargs: it's a fantastic tool, but it's going to cause problems if any of your files or "search patterns" have spaces or glob characters (eg., "*").

Rather, use a tool that expects a search pattern, [find](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find).

```
cat boards | while read pattern
find $work -name "${pattern}*" -exec cp {} /path/to/destination +
done
```

That will read in each line of `boards` as a search pattern. `find` will then look in the `$work` directory to find files (and folders!) that match `${pattern}*`; each found item (file or folder) will be passed to cp as a properly-escaped parameter (in the `{}` spot), and it will do `xargs`-like minimization of the number of `cp` processes it starts because of the `+` (if you wanted exactly one process per found item, you'd use a `;` instead - be sure to escape it properly, though).

`find` has a rich set of filters you can apply to narrow down your search. Of particular note is the `-type f` option which will limit the results to file.

Note that the `cp` command may fail if there are folders in the argument list passed in from `find`; using the `-type f` filter will prevent that.

Note also that the `cp` command will "flatten" the output directory - if `$work` has subdirectories which happen to have matching files, those files will be copied straight to `/path/to/destination`. If you want to only copy files at the top level of `$work`, the `-maxdepth` filter (probably with a value of 1: `-maxdepth 1`) will prevent `find` from recursing too deep down the file system.

Note also that `find` is case-sensitive. If you don't want it to be, you can use `-iname` instead of `-name` to do a case-insensitive search.

If there are any other command line parameters you want to give `cp`, just put them in front of the `{}` (eg., `cp -r {}` to copy directories that match the search pattern).

Comment: Good point about strange file names. There is a solution both ways, but IFS= and -print0 get ugly. A potential tweak to your find solution, maybe use `-exec cp "{}"` to catch the inevitable spaces?

Comment: The {} handles that already; quoting them will just send a literal pair of curly braces to cp, which will complain about no such file.

Comment: Just tested, and we're both right! :)

The bare braces works fine even with filenames including a space, as does double quoted braces (`"{}"`).

The way I thought would not work, using single quoted braces (`'{}'`) worked fine as well. I assumed the the single quotes would have passed the braces as arguments, but I guess not.

Escaping the braces succeeds.Escaping any of quotes fails. Escaping the braces inside any type of quotes fails with `cannot stat "\{\}"`. Escaping quotes with escaped braces fails with a `cannot stat` with the filename as if it started with a quote.

Comment: Deep; the curlies are arguments to find, so of course quoting them would work. Sorry, I had a dumb there.

Comment: Nope, my dumb. I was unaware the curlies escaped properly.